# ScriptError: Error: Unexpected type for OrGroup: 4 in google sheet while migrating ga3 audiences to ga4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Facing the below error while trying to migrate the ga3 audiences to ga4 using Ga4 migrator for google audiences

ScriptError: Error: Unexpected type for OrGroup: 4 in google sheet

migrating ga3 audiences to ga4 as a part of GA4 migration plan